# Spring swallow exception during startup

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, ignite

I have bean (don't mind `try catch` it is for debug purpose):

```java
    @Bean
    public IgniteEntityConfiguration articleIgniteEntityConfig() {
        try {
            return IgniteEntityConfiguration.builder()
                    .cacheName("ArticleCache")
                    .dbTableName("ARTICLE")
                    .valueClass(Article.class)
                    .build();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("bean errr", e);
            throw e;
        }

    }
```

In `IgniteEntityConfiguration` I validate passed class and thrown exception if needed.

### flow

In logs I have:

1. Error logged by logger `log.error("bean errr", e);`;
2. Other info lines.
3. Error from @Controller that is using bean that intercity uses `articleIgniteEntityConfig`; **And here app stops**.

If I delete `try catch` block, the error is not even logged (exception is thrown - I checked it with debugger).

### question

Why is that? Shouldn't the first exception in beans stop the app?

Comment: Can you share few lines of code showing how this bean is used in controller?

Comment: I would like to but it is like 5 classes.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. I don't get meaningful error because in `IgniteRepositoryFactory` (ignite-spring-data_2.2) all cause errors are swallowed and only this error is thrown:

```java
                    throw new IgniteException("Failed to initialize Ignite repository factory. Ignite instance or"
                        + " IgniteConfiguration or a path to Ignite's spring XML "
                        + "configuration must be defined in the"
                        + " application configuration");
```

### full method

```java
 private Ignite igniteForRepoConfig(RepositoryConfig config) {
        try {
            String igniteInstanceName = evaluateExpression(config.igniteInstance());
            return (Ignite)ctx.getBean(igniteInstanceName);
        }
        catch (BeansException ex) {
            try {
                String igniteConfigName = evaluateExpression(config.igniteCfg());
                IgniteConfiguration cfg = (IgniteConfiguration)ctx.getBean(igniteConfigName);
                try {
                    // first try to attach to existing ignite instance
                    return Ignition.ignite(cfg.getIgniteInstanceName());
                }
                catch (Exception ignored) {
                    // nop
                }
                return Ignition.start(cfg);
            }
            catch (BeansException ex2) {
                try {
                    String igniteSpringCfgPath = evaluateExpression(config.igniteSpringCfgPath());
                    String path = (String)ctx.getBean(igniteSpringCfgPath);
                    return Ignition.start(path);
                }
                catch (BeansException ex3) {
                    throw new IgniteException("Failed to initialize Ignite repository factory. Ignite instance or"
                        + " IgniteConfiguration or a path to Ignite's spring XML "
                        + "configuration must be defined in the"
                        + " application configuration");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```